# Using a tstamp to delete files has started failing

Tags: ant

I use a tstamp to build a fileset of old files to delete. This has been working well, but since around the start of the month it fails.

The error is:

> Date of 08/09/2021 01:25 PM Cannot be parsed correctly. It should be in MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM AM_PM format.

```
<target name="RemoveOldBackups" >
    <tstamp>
        <format property="BKRetention" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a" locale="en,UK" offset="-${Backup.Retention.Number}" unit="${Backup.Retention.Unit}"/>
    </tstamp>
    <for list="${Database.List}" param="database" parallel="${parallel}" threadCount="${threadCount}">
        <sequential>
            <echo message="Working on Database: @{database} Full path: ${Database.List.@{database}.Location}${Database.List.@{database}.FileName}" />
            <delete>
                <fileset dir="${Database.List.@{database}.LocalBackup}" includes="**/*.bkp">
                    <date datetime="${BKRetention}" when="before"/>
                </fileset>
            </delete>
        </sequential>
    </for>
</target>
```

The script itself hasn't changed in that time period, so it must be something environment related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation I established that the machine was running a version on Ant from 2012. After updating to the latest release the problem is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled on this thread when tasked with resolving a similar message - "Date of 03/29/2023 10:43 AM Cannot be parsed correctly. It should be in MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM AM_PM format."

In my case the development effort was moving from a legacy build environment to a newly created Jenkins agent.  In the process they (apparently unknowingly) went from using JDK 1.8 to using JDK 18.  When using the newer JDK the ANT target failed - but once JAVA_HOME was set to the 1.8 JDK, things magically started working again.

Answer (score -1):

https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/tstamp.html has "aa" instead of "a" in the pattern. Might be worth a try. An the locale should be "en,GB" from my point of view (or that is the actual issue and should be de,DE).

Comment: you'd better write this as a comment since it doesn't include a solution

Comment: I can't comment as my reputation is still too low.